# VBA to click a webpage button

Tags: vba, html

I would like to click a webpage button using VBA. I tried several options (please see the code below) but none of them seems work. If instead of *click* I use *focus*, it selects the button that I want to push, however the click command is not working. What other methods can I try?

```
Sub SubmitInfo()

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        IE.Visible = True
        IE.navigate "http://www.ecotransit.org/calculation.en.html"

    Do While IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

    ' 1st option

    IE.document.getElementById("calculationBT").Click

    ' 2nd option

    IE.document.getElementsByClassName("formGreenButton")(0).Click

    ' 3rd option

    Set htmlColl = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
                    Do While IE.document.readyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Loop
                        For Each htmlInput In htmlColl
                            If Trim(htmlInput.Type) = "submit" Then
                            htmlInput.Click

                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next htmlInput
    ' 4th option

    Set htmlColl = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
                    Do While IE.document.readyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Loop
                        For Each htmlInput In htmlColl
                            If Trim(htmlInput.Value) = "CALCULATE" Then
                            htmlInput.Click

                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next htmlInput

    End Sub
```

Below is the button HTML code that I want to click

```
<input id="calculationBT" type="submit" class="formGreenButton" value="CALCULATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IE.document.getElementById("calculationBT").Click
```

should do the job but you must be sure that there is only one occurence of the id, which should be in this case.

Comment: I tried this in my code and did not work. Can I use something different than I used so far in code? (please see the code above). Thanks for your reply!

Comment: You'll need to fill out the fields of the form first and then click on the submit button

Comment: @area9, I have also filled the fields; it does not have any relevance.